# I want to update the already printed text from console without deleting what the user already typed

Tags: python

```py
import os
from _thread import start_new_thread

iList = ["Hello", "World"]

def func(p):
    while True:
        print("\n".join(iList))
        os.system("CLS")

start_new_thread(func, ("Placeholder",))


while True:
    iList.append(input("Write Something: "))
```

I want the `iList` be updated in realtime without ruining what the user already typed, although it doesn't delete what the user already typed in the `input` but it shows that it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the console doesn't really work like that.  Under Unix you'd use the [`curses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) but (due to your use of `CLS`) I presume you're under Windows hence this is less helpful.  the [curses HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) contains a suggestion of a Windows alternative, as well as examples of how you'd go about handling user input, keypress by keypress